# How to export Scratch project to Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4, game-development, mit-scratch

I'm a Scratch Developer and I want to start creating games in UE4. Since most of the functionalities in Unreal are created on blueprints I'm wondering, is there a way to export my existing Scratch game to an Unreal project?

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible. Scratch and Unreal Engine are vastly different engines. They don't even compile to the same language, and have very different functionalities.